# Are AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine and AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType compatible?

Tags: c++, formatting, clang-format

There's a repository which I want to use Clang Format with that has a peculiar coding style. It breaks the return type, but it also puts short function definitions on one line:

```c++
bool
isConditionMet() const { return _isConditionMet; }
```

When the function isn't short:

```c++
bool
MyClass::isConditionMet() const {
    bool first = computeA();
    return first && computeB();
}
```

I'm trying to make the *.clang-format* file match as closely as possible, but I couldn't get this to work. This is a minimal example (I eliminated all irrelevant settings):

```
---
Language:        Cpp
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: All
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: All
...
```

When running it over this:

```c++
class Test
{
public:
  void doNothing() {}

  int giveMe() { return 42; }

  int compute()
  {
    int i = 0;
    i += 42;
    return i;
  }
};
```

I got this:

```c++
class Test {
public:
  void
  doNothing() {}

  int
  giveMe() {
    return 42;
  }

  int
  compute() {
    int i = 0;
    i += 42;
    return i;
  }
};
```

Instead of what I expected:

```c++
class Test {
public:
  void
  doNothing() {}

  int
  giveMe() { return 42; }

  int
  compute() {
    int i = 0;
    i += 42;
    return i;
  }
};
```

The two settings `AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine` and `AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType` appear to be conflicting with each other. Does Clang Format allow for my desired formatting style?

Version:

```
$ clang-format-5.0 --version
clang-format version 5.0.0-3~16.04.1 (tags/RELEASE_500/final)
```

Comment: I'm encountering a similar issue, but with `BraceWrapping: {AfterFunction: true}` and `AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine`